# How to delete/refresh specific migration in laravel

Tags: laravel, cygwin

I am working on a large project which has many migrations. I want to add a column in a table and I don't want to maintain multiple migrations for one table. How can I do that? Is there any way to migrate:refresh for only one migration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think migrations are designed to run sequentially as each one could depend on an earlier one.

For example, migration#1 could create a table and migration#2 could add some extra fields to that table. If you tried to run migration#2 without every having run #1 then it would fail.

When you run artisan migrate then it will only run migrations that haven't already been applied unless you use migrate:refresh in which case it will reset and re-run all migrations.

If you are dead-set on only running one migration - you could temporarily remove all the migrations you *do not want run* from the directory, and run the migration command. Then move the rest back. It's a hacky workaround, but it would do the trick.

There is ONE MORE alternative that I think might even suit you best:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/selected/
```

where the migration you want is inside the /selected/ directory (which you'll need to create).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new migration which will be adding new column, i.e.:

`Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('additional_field');
});`

And the run `php artisan migrate`

This will update your table with new column and not interfere with other tables.